# VBA userform only works once

Tags: vba, excel

I am Creating a Userform in Excel 2013 to make entering data into an inventory file easier at my workplace. The userform 
([Userform and Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOMAH.jpg)) will run and I can enter multiple  new items (Ignore the Update existing entry button I haven't started on that yet) into the inventory file, but once I close the form opening it again causes the error 
"Run time error '-2147417848 (80010108)' Method 'Value" of 'Range' failed" 
to appear and the Debug seems to highlight a different object each time I try it.

```
Private Sub New_Data_Click() 
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lPart As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Worksheet")

lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:"*", SearchOrder:=xlRows,
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn=xlValues).Row + 1
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.EnterChemical.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.EnterNotes.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.EnterLot.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.EnterItem.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.SpinButton1.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.EnterManf.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.EnterLoc.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.EnterTare.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.EnterGross.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.EnterUnit.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.EnterExp.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 16).Value = Date

    If Me.Expire.Value = True Then
        .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = "Expire"
    ElseIf Me.Retest.Value = True Then
        .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = "Retest"
    EndIf

    If Me.API.Value = True Then
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = "Yes"
    EndIf
EndWith

EndSub

Private Sub Closefrm.Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_Change()
    Reference_no.Caption = SpinButton1.Value
```

So this all works one time but I dont know why it fails the second. Do I need to have a different closing function on the button or I am completely missing something.

Comment: A form object is no longer usable after its Unload-ed.  Just bake a new cookie with the `New` keyword.

Comment: @HansPassant I am surprised that you don't have a [Code Review](codereview.stackexchange.com) profile.   [Code Review](codereview.stackexchange.com) could use you.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your help I implemented that this morning and it worked perfectly